change the behaviour for plotly autoscale numbers to M(million) on y-axis and hover box
I have a data frame df and df has two columns named calmonth, amt_sales.
I use box function inplotly.express module to generate box plot for each month.
Here is the code:
fig = px.box(
    df,
    y='amt_sales',
    x='calmonth',
)

while the plot looks like this, as you can see the data on yaxis and hover box are scaled to M(million).

I wish to scale to ten thousands as 万 in chinese for data in yaxis and hover box .
For hover box I tried to add a new column to df named amt_sales_converted, then added it to hover_data parameter.
For yaxis I used np.linspace to cut the min and max value of amt_sales into 10 bins and pass relative values to parameter tickvals & ticktext in fig.update_yaxes()
df['amt_sales_converted'] = df.amt_sales/Decimal('10000')
fig = px.box(
    df,
    y='amt_sales',
    x='calmonth',
    hover_data=['amt_sales_converted']
)

ymin = np.min(df.amt_sales.to_numpy().astype('float'))
ymax = np.max(df.amt_sales.to_numpy().astype('float'))


values = np.linspace(ymin, ymax, 10)
labels = [f"{round(v/10000, 2)}万" for v in values]

fig.update_yaxes(tickvals=values, ticktext=labels)

The result told me that it displayed scaled to ten thousands data only when i hovered on fliers and didn't work when i hovered on the box itself.
The yaxis's data is not a integer due to the cut in np.linspace.

I wonder if plotly has some configuration or functions to achieve this requirement?

The simplest would be to plot the amt_sales_converted data directly and set '万' as ticksuffix for the yaxis. By default, hover data for this axis will also inherit the specified suffix :
fig = px.box(
    df,
    y='amt_sales_converted',
    x='calmonth'
)

fig.update_yaxes(ticksuffix='万')


yes this would be the simplest way.
And I find exponentformat parameter in fig.update_yaxes(), it is designed to format tick exponent. But it seems only support 'E', 'none', 'B' not customized function or string.
Is there any chances that we can modify the behaviour use other functions or configurations?

@Lisen Sorry I didn't get your comment and then I forgot to reply. exponentformat accepts only "none" | "e" | "E" | "power" | "SI" | "B", there is no way to customize it.
